# Separate date and time into two columns in R and summarize the rows based on time of the day

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyverse, tidyr

How can I separate date and time into two columns? And then summarise all these rows and take the average value for every 12 hrs of the day? (Essentially only have two rolls of data for every day instead 49 rolls, each roll is the average temperature for the 1st/2nd 12 hours of the day.) Please see the pictures below, thank you so much for the help!

Current code:

```
test <- weather %>% 
  unite(date, Year.Month.Day.Hour.Minutes.in.YYYY, MM, DD, sep="-") %>% 
  unite(time, HH24, MI.format.in.Local.time, sep=":") %>% 
  mutate(timestamp=paste(date, time) %>% 
           as.POSIXct(., format="%Y-%m-%d %H:%M")) %>%
  select(timestamp, temperature)
```

Current output:
[image: Current output]

Expected output:
[image: Expected output]

Comment: Please add data in reproducible form which we can copy and use. Images don't help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this?

```
weather %>% 
  unite(date, Year.Month.Day.Hour.Minutes.in.YYYY, MM, DD, sep="-") %>% 
  unite(time, HH24, MI.format.in.Local.time, sep=":") %>% 
  mutate(timestamp=paste(date, time) %>% 
           as.POSIXct(., format="%Y-%m-%d %H:%M")) %>%
  select(timestamp, temperature) %>% 
  group_by(
    Date = as.Date(timestamp), 
    Time = if_else(lubridate::am(timestamp), "Morning", "Afternoon")
  ) %>% 
  summarise(
    `Average Temperature` = mean(Air.Temperature.in.degrees.C)
  )
```